# How to make this pandas query?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a simple data frame df shown below. The clean_grams column is a python list or NaN. The list can have elements in them or be empty.

```
    clean_grams                                      part
0          []       E1028364E7BA353750620317F8ED618187EA76B5
1         NaN       4C5AA421DF5FF650A63695C33AAF35531E79FC1E
2          []       637148EF9EE16F4A0BA9A44C72330F32A7C8C9BB
3          ['dog']  C48B08CA63359A4849B00D9A3622A604BB3EDB80
4         NaN       932FEB7317F2E1ACEC569B9C49C3B4563C50D946
```

Now to select all the rows which have lists which are not empty, I tried:

```
df[df['clean_grams'] != []]
```

But I get a value error: http://pastebin.com/ugQuFqRD

Kindly help!

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a bug @elyase, it should be written as `DF[DF['clean_grams']!=[[],]*len(DF)]`.

Consider what is going on under the hood, with `df['clean_grams'] != []`, `numpy` can't determine whether an `array` is a `[]` (since `array` is also a `list`) or should it broadcast and compare it to `[[],]*len(DF)]`. So we has to help it here by specifically telling it to do the latter.

The exception message reads `ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 5 vs 0`, which explains it all.

Comment: this is the sort of stuff that makes pandas so hard for people. it taunts you with a clean abstraction, but it breaks all the time :) thanks for your help.